# Read file, search text and replace all the line

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, text, replace

I have a TXT file with some values that I want to replace. For example:

```
"FirtsColor"        "176 174 145 255"
"SecondColor"       "204 204 145 255"
"ThirdColor"        "164 240 115 255"
```

With my code I can replace the text and add the new values, but still having the old ones.

```
"FirtsColor"        "176 174 145 255"
"SecondColor"       "255 110 195 255"       "204 204 145 255"
"ThirdColor"        "164 240 115 255"
```

```
Private Sub Button1_Click() Handles Button1.Click
    If Not File = Nothing Then
        Dim filePath As String = File
        Dim reader As New IO.StreamReader(filePath)
        Dim contents As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
        reader.Close()
        contents = contents.Replace(Chr(34) & "SecondColor" & Chr(34), Chr(34) & "SecondColor" & Chr(34) & "        " & Chr(34) & "255 110 195 255" & Chr(34))
        Dim writer As New IO.StreamWriter(filePath)
        writer.WriteLine(contents)
        writer.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

What I want?

- Search a text in the whole file ("SecondColor" in this case)
- Remove all the line ("SecondColor" "204 204 145 255")
- Write the same word again with the new RGBA values ("SecondColor" "255 110 195 255")

What I get with my current code?

- Search a text in the whole file ("SecondColor")
- Replace the text and add the new values ("SecondColor" "255 110 195 255" "204 204 145 255")

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: It's very unclear what you're looking for.

Comment: How many lines do you have in this file?

Comment: @Steve Over 4000 lines but I only need edit a 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well 4000 lines of this kind are not a big enough memory problem, so you could read all of them in memory and execute a loop to search your data, replace the whole line with the desidered value and write it back to disk

```
Sub Main
    Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines("D:\temp\testcolor.txt")
    for x = 0 to lines.Count() - 1
        if lines(x).Trim().StartsWith(Chr(34) & "SecondColor" & Chr(34)) Then
            lines(x) = string.Format("{0,-20}{1}", _
                       Chr(34) & "SecondColor" & Chr(34), _
                       Chr(34) & "255.255.255.255" & Chr(34))
        End if
    Next
    File.WriteAllLines("D:\temp\testcolor.txt", lines)
End Sub
```

[File.ReadLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines(v=vs.110).aspx) split your data in separate lines, so it is easy to replace the whole line with your inputs

Comment: Added a little improvement to force the text in the first column (the color column) to be 20 characters wide